# Media query condition styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, media-queries, styled-components

`<Main/>` has an optional prop `isFirstPage` so if it has this prop it'll be with media query.
Snippet below works fine, but I suppose there is a better solution.

```
export default styled(Main)`
  ...my styles...
  ${props => props.isFirstPage && '@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {padding: 16px}'}
`;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realized that we can use this as:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const YourComponent = styled.div`
  //...
  
  ${props => props.isFirstPage && css`
     @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
       padding: 8px 8px 24px 8px
     }
  `}
`;
```

This is solution for me.